# apache thrift struct having extra Java interface

Tags: java, thrift

I'm working on a project using thrift

in .thrift file, there are a couple of structs.

```
struct ATypeRequest{}

struct BTypeRequest{}

struct CTypeRequest{}
```

These will be generated as Java classes, which all implement TBase interface.

```
public class ATypeRequest implements TBase{}
public class BTypeRequest implements TBase{}
public class CTypeRequest implements TBase{}
```

Is there a way to make them all implement another self-defined interface, say interface MyRequest. How can I do that? Or thrift doesn't support this at all?

Thanks for any help